# How to create a page which allows a parameter in url in apostrophe-cms (for instance article/:id)

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I would like to allow the user to create a page with a dynamic slug. Something like /idea/:id. The id is then parsed and can be used by the widgets on the page, accessing req.params.

It's easy to get it working with /idea?id=1. But would prefer the "pretty" alternative.

To clarify I want the user to be able to make this page and create the slug in the CMS. It's possible to do it with the express instance, but then the user loses the ability to manage the page.

Anyone any ideas? Couldn't easily find a solution,

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!

Create module: *idea-pages*

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-custom-pages',

  name: 'idea',

  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.dispatch('/:id', (req, callback) => {
      callback(null);
    });
  }
};
```

Create page type in app.js

```
'apostrophe-pages': {
      types: [
        {
          name: 'default',
          label: 'Default'
        },
        {
          name: 'idea',
          label: 'Idea'
        }
      ]
 },
```

Comment: Yep, that's the preferred solution. `apostrophe-pieces-pages` builds on the same mechanism to provide URLs for individual pieces. 

Your example doesn't spell it out specifically, but if anyone else is wondering, inside the function you can access `req.params.id`.

Comment: @TomBoutell Im trying to use this :id in load a widget, but it seems load is called before dispatch, so this ID isn't avaialble. I need to make an async call per widget on the page with this ID. What is the preferred solution? For now all I can think of is create a Promise function in widget.load, and add it to the req object and then fire it on pageBeforeServe adding the ID at that moment.

Comment: You would need to pass the :id as an option to the widget in the template.

Comment: How would you do this dynamically? Maybe I misunnderstood

Comment: If it was a query parameter you could just pass it as `data.query.id` in your template, since templates can see `req.query` as `data.query`. `req.params` is not automatically in templates so you would write a helper function for that, returning `apos.templates.contextReq.params`.

Comment: @TomBoutell the point is I want to fetch the data server side, per widget, I would prefer the widget manages it's own data. Of course I could do it with ajax, but would prefer server side rendering. Load seems to be the last place widget could do their own async actions?

Comment: That's correct. `load` is normally the last chance for the widget, and it's true that the "remainder" of the URL has not been dispatched at that time. You could address this by parsing `req.url` yourself in `load`. Or, you could create an array of the relevant widgets as a property of `req` in `load`, and do further work on them in an `apostrophe-pages:beforeSend` event handler that just iterates over that array property, without having to go digging to find them anywhere else. This is attractive because by the time the event handler runs `req.params.id` will be available.